# Menu Passo a Passo ou ProgressBar

Tags: javascript, css

Estava tentando fazer um menu passo a passo, daí cheguei nisso. Minha intenção era clicar no primeiro círculo, acender o passo 1 na cor verde e passar para o próximo passo, tornando a linha entre eles verde (como já está no código). E assim sucessivamente até o passo 3. Alguma ideia de como fazer isso?? Javascript?

```css
.container{
    width: 100%;
}
.progressbar{
    counter-reset: step;
}
.progressbar li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
.progressbar li:before{
    content: counter(step);
    counter-increment: step;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto 10px auto;
    border-radius: 58%;
    background-color: white;
}
.progressbar li:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    top: 15px;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
}
.progressbar li:first-child:after{
    content: none;
}
.progressbar li.active{
    color: green;
}
.progressbar li.active:before{
    border-color: green;
}
.progressbar li.active + li:after{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <ul class="progressbar">
        <li class="active">Passo 1</li>
        <li>Passo 2</li>
        <li>Passo 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @dvd eu imaginei dessa forma, talvez tenha outra melhor

Comment: Sim, mas qual seria objetivo? Apenas clicar e ascender os círculos?

Comment: @dvd É que tipo, são 3 passos: Se Cadastrar, Realizar inscrição, anexar comprovantes (e finalizar). Talvez ficaria melhor se os passos ficassem escondidos (a partir do primeiro) e só aparecessem conforme fosse clicando. Mas não precisa estar relacionando com nenhum progresso do usuário em si pq eu só vou usar na tela principal pra tipo já dá uma ideia do que o usuário terá pela frente, de maneira bem lúdica.

Comment: algo como isso https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/form-wizard-using-tabs

Comment: Veja: https://jsfiddle.net/5yz2d4hj/

Comment: @dvd tem algum "evento" js pra fazer com que essa linha verde siga lentamente para o próximo passo? Claro, nesse caso acho que teria q mudar o css